# stored procedure call to project and check for exists record c#

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2017

I have this stored procedure:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Save_Customer]

    @CustomerID int output,
    @CustomerName nvarchar (150)

    

as
    if (select count(*) FROM dbo.CustomersTbl WHERE CustomersTbl.CustomerID= @CustomerID)>0
    BEGIN

        return -3
    END 
ELSE    
   if (select count(*) FROM dbo.CustomersTbl WHERE CustomersTbl.CustomerName= @CustomerName)=0
     BEGIN
       insert into CustomersTbl
                (CustomerID,CustomerName)
                values
                (@CustomerID,@CustomerName)
                return -2
     END
            else
            begin
            return -4
            
    END
```

in the project i have class called DataAccessLayer this call has this method to add,update or delete :

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
    if (param != null)
    {
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    }
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now i have create another Layer Called Business Layer Folder contain class called CLS_AddUpdateDelete and it has this code to save customer :

```
public void Save_Customers(int Customer_Id, string Customer_Name)
{
    Data_Layer.DataAccessLayer DAL = new Data_Layer.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[0].Value = Customer_Id;
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar,150);
    param[1].Value = Customer_Name;
    DAL.ExecuteCommand("Save_Customer", param);
    DAL.Close();
}
```

in the form i have button :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Customer Name");
        return;
    }
    Saving.Save_Customers(Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text.Trim()),textBox3.Text.Trim());
    MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully", "Add Customer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    ClearControls.ResetAllControls(this);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = GetInfo.GetAllFroDataGridView();
    DataTable tbl = GetLastRecord.GetLastRecord();
    textBox4.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows[0][0])).ToString();
}
```

what i want is how to know if this record is exists in database and if it is exists i need to popup message to use that record is exists in database .

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in the button click

```
Boolean emp_exist = false;
string query = select * from CustomersTbl where CustomerID = '"+yourid+"';
SqlCommand myCommand0 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader myreader = myCommand0.ExecuteReader();
while (myreader.Read())
{   
 emp_exist = true; 
}
if (!emp_exist)
{
   //your code  
}  
else
{
 //add your message employee exist 
}
```

Comment: Can You Please Modify The Above Code ?

Comment: check now add your table and id in query and add your code inside the if (!emp_exist) and message inside else part  i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add an output parameter with bit type to stored procedure parameters and
set it as 1 if there is any record with your conditions.
after that, you can check the output parameter and decide what to do.

Comment: i cant post the code but its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the stored procedure, you can execute a "select statement" and call [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to check if the item existed in database. If it does not exist, the return value of the method will be "null".

You can refer to the following code.

```
string connString = @"connection string";
string sql = "select * from CustomersTbl where CustomerID='" + textBoxID.Text + "'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        if(cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
            Console.WriteLine("not exist");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```